# Does rsync preserve ACL?

Tags: linux, solaris, rsync, access-control-list

I am using Solaris 9 and planning to go for a Linux OEL 6x now. 
I will be using rsync for the data movement from Solaris from to Linux server. I am really concerned about the ACL[ FACL- getfacl, setfacl] for files and users in my Solaris box- Does rsync preserve ACL properties by any chance.

Answer (score 11):

If you pass `-A`, it will try its hardest.

Comment: And you're running a not-entirely-ancient rsync version... and $DEITY only knows if it'll do it correctly between Solaris and Linux... but testing will quickly determine the limits of that.

Comment: ACL's are very dependent on the FS the files are stored on, so often they can't be preserved.  It may also depend on what FS you're using on Solaris 9 (UFS/ZFS/etc.) and what type of FS you're moving the data to on your Linux box (ext[234], jfs, btrfs, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Rsync also provides a `--chmod` flag [(see this answer)](https://serverfault.com/a/455217/130437) which will let you entirely rewrite the standard permission in transit.  If you set-up the new target default ACL and pass `rsync` the right permissions, you get the right result.  Of course, this only works when all files get similar ACLs.

This probably isn't the answer you're looking for but it could be one more tool for the right problem.

I'd think the bigger issue is possible impedance mismatch between ACL implementations.